# leaflet R changing shapes color based on different layers

Tags: r, leaflet

I am working on multiple layer's basemap with circles shapes.
I combine CartoDB.DarkMatter basemap and maps from David Rumsey historical maps collection.

I display my data with circles and color and transparency attributes looks fine on DarkMatter basemap but not on historical maps. (too clear)

How can I adapt the circles color based on layers ? (ex:   #3182bd (for historical basemaps); #3182bd (for DarkMatter basemap )

```
leaflet() %>%
          addCircles(lng = 0.0, lat = 0.0, radius = 10^6, color = "#6baed6",    weight = 3) %>%
          addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatterNoLabels, group = "DarkMatter") %>%
          addTiles("https://maps.georeferencer.com/georeferences/673422615974/2017-12-29T21:36:14.564535Z/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=D7AwmpRP1H6pUic6DIK3",
                   group ="Wassende-Grade-Kaart van de Aetiopische Ocean, van Keulen, Joannes, 1680") %>%
          addTiles("https://maps.georeferencer.com/georeferences/190155356360/2017-12-30T15:04:20.007647Z/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=D7AwmpRP1H6pUic6DIK3",
                   group ="La Guinee et Pays circomvoisins, Sanson, Nicolas, 1656") %>%
          addLayersControl(
            baseGroups = c("DarkMatter", "Wassende-Grade-Kaart van de Aetiopische Ocean, van Keulen, Joannes, 1680", "La Guinee et Pays circomvoisins, Sanson, Nicolas, 1656"), position ="topleft")
```

Comment: You will probalbyl have to use the baseLayerChange-event...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645617/leaflet-popups-for-specific-base-maps